# firmata_test does not start

Tags: raspbian, arm

Im trying to get firmata_test from firmata.org working on my raspi3 running raspian up-to-date version. What depencies or programms do I need to have installed to successful start the firmata_test ? ( I've tried both: 32-/64-Bit for Linux is there a special Version for ARM chips around? Or can someone show me the right direction to compile it on my own?) None of them loads up anything after double-click and press 'Execute'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a pre-built ARM version, so you'll have to build from [sources](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/firmata_test/firmata_test.tar.gz). This seems to be using wxWidgets, so you'll have to install `wx3.0-headers`, `libwxgtk3.0-dev` and `libwxbase3.0-dev` before you build. There may be other missing dependencies, and Firmata also seems to use wxWidgets 2.8, so you may end up building old wxWidgets from sources as well.